# Extending an EditText View in Android: Not letting me use my custom methods. why?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-studio, android-custom-view

Okay so I am trying to extend the EditText view by creating my own, but whenever I instantiate it inside my MainActivity class it doesn't let me use the new methods I created!  Any help is appreciated! Below is my code:

```
//Sticky.java

public class Sticky extends EditText {

  private CharSequence title = "";

  public Sticky(Context context) {
     super(context);
     Log.d("STICKY CONSTRUCTOR","Created new sticky!");
  }

  public Sticky(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
     super(context, attrs);
  }

  public Sticky(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
     super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  public void setTitle(CharSequence text) {
     this.title = text;
  }

  public CharSequence getTitle() {
     return this.title;
  }

}
```

I tried using inner classes first, but that didn't work so I thought about moving it into it's own separate file. Sadly, that didn't work either.

```
//MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    static final int STICKY_NOTE_HEIGHT = 180, STICKY_NOTE_WIDTH = 180;
    EditText mEdit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      mEdit = new Sticky(this); 

      mEdit.setId(1);

      mEdit.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
      mEdit.setTextSize(24);
      mEdit.setHeight(STICKY_NOTE_HEIGHT);
      mEdit.setWidth(STICKY_NOTE_WIDTH);

      mEdit.setTitle("Sticky " + mEdit2.getId());//ERROR

      FrameLayout.LayoutParams params  = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

      params.setMargins(stickyNoteLeftMargin, stickyNoteTopMargin, 0, 0);
      frameLayout.addView(mEdit2,params); //add a new view and make it use the new layout rules
}
```

When I run the app with the `mEdit.setTitle();` commented out, it works perfectly fine. The only problem is when I uncomment it and try to use the custom method I created in the Sticky.java file. The error Android Studio gives me is `Error:(93, 23) error: cannot find symbol method setTitle(String)`. I looked all over for answers but to no avail. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? It's probably something really simple and I am just over looking it :(

Comment: show me your definition of mEdit
mEdit = (Sticky)findViewById...

Comment: where is your title String you pass to the method ?

Comment: Sorry about that! I added the definition and I passed in the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead :

```
mEdit.setTitle();//ERROR
```

try :

```
mEdit.setTitle("A random Title");
```

Comment: As an extension of this, you can't set it to nothing, you have to set it to an actual string. It can even be null, or an empty string, you just have to explicitly define it as such.

Comment: @mtOs sorry about that! I made the change but it is still not working!

Comment: @BigD You should change also `EditText mEdit;` to `Sticky mEdit;` since you want to use your Sticky widget

Comment: OMG THANK YOU! I can't believe I made such an easy mistake!